# Validate BASE64 string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I want to validate whether string stored in a variable is a valid BASE64 string or not in my stored procedure.

For Example :

```
declare @source varbinary(max), @encoded varchar(max), @decoded varbinary(max)
set @source = convert(varbinary(max), 'Hello Base64')
set @encoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable(''@source''))', 'varchar(max)')
```

Now I want to validate whether @encoded has valid BASE64 string or not.

Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
declare @b64 varchar(max) = 'SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0'

select UTF8Encoding
    ,case when UTF8Encoding is null then 0 else 1 end as Valid  from (
select CAST(CAST(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@b64"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') as varchar(MAX)) UTF8Encoding
) a
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will produce a false positive when you have a value that doesn't break the rules that would decode base64. e.g., Player11